# Determine whether a SAS dataset is a table or view

Tags: view, sas, proc-sql

I'm trying to determine, given a SAS dataset's name, whether it is a table or view.

The context is that I have a data step where I iterate over a list of dataset names, and if the dataset is a table (and not a view) I'd like to perform a call execute to a sql procedure which drops the table whose name is specified. As it stands now, the code works as intended but throws several warnings of the form

> WARNING: File WORK.datasetname.DATA does not exist.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
data _null_;

set work.ds_list;

tbl_loc = scan(tbl_name,1,'.');
if(tbl_loc = 'WORK') then do;
    drop_string = catx(' ',
                       'proc sql; drop table',
                       tbl_name,
                       '; quit;');
    call execute (drop_string);
    put ' ** Queueing call to drop table ' tbl_name;
end;
run;
```

So how do I determine from the dataset's name whether it is a view or table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `EXIST` function will help you here.

```
if exist(tbl_name,'DATA') then memtype = 'TABLE'; else
if exist(tbl_name,'VIEW') then memtype = 'VIEW';

drop_statements = catx
( ' ',
  'proc sql; drop', memtype, tbl_name, '; quit;'
);
```

From Docs

> **Syntax**
>
> **EXIST(member-name <, member-type <, generation>>)**
>
> **Required Argument**
>
> **member-name**
>
> is a character constant, variable, or expression that specifies the
>   SAS library member. If member-name is blank or a null string, then
>   EXIST uses the value of the *LAST* system variable as the member name.
>
> **Optional Arguments**
>
> **member-type**
>
> is a character constant, variable, or expression that specifies the
>   type of SAS library member. A few common member types include ACCESS,
>   CATALOG, DATA, and VIEW. If you do not specify a member-type, then the
>   member type DATA is assumed.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work for me. Warnings are gone but no tables are recognized:

`data work.test_data;

test_col = .;
output;
run;

data _null_;

if (not exist('work.test_data','TABLE')) then 
    put 'Not recognized as table';

run;`

Comment: In your first line did you mean to write `if exist(tbl_name, 'DATA') then memtype = 'TABLE';`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than 'create it' how about using SASHELP.VTABLE to determine if it's a VIEW or DATA.

```
data temp /view=temp;
set sashelp.class;
run;

data check;
set sashelp.vtable;
where libname='WORK';
run;
```

Note that the memtype in this case is VIEW. You could probably join your data set to the table as well or do some form of lookup, but a join would be pretty straightforward.

Then once you have the data sets, you can use a PROC DATASETS to drop them all at once rather than one at a time. You don't indicate what initially created this list, but how that list is created is important and could possibly simplify this a lot.

```
proc datasets lib=work;
    delete temp / memtype=view;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Hi @Reeza, don't think this approach is viable for me as querying sashelp.vtable appears to hang my session. Perhaps my environment is too clogged?

Comment: It's possible if you have too many tables there. Then you could use PROC DATASETS itself to create the list. This mostly works if all the files are in few libraries or a single library.

Answer (score 0):

so - you'd like to delete all datasets, but not views, from a library?

Simply use the ([documented](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1469bsvzgd33jn0z4xecxmx2bgo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)) `delete` procedure:

```
proc delete lib=work data=_all_ (memtype=data) ;
run;
```